# Why won't fr units work with grid-template-rows on CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I can't get the `grid-template-rows` to work with `fr` units. I can get the row height to change with other units like pixels but not with `fr` units.

I don't understand why this isn't working as the `fr` units are working with `grid-template-columns`.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item"> 1 </div>
  <div class="item"> 2 </div>
  <div class="item"> 3 </div>
  <div class="item"> 4 </div>
  <div class="item"> 5 </div>
  <div class="item"> 6 </div>
  <div class="item"> 7 </div>
  <div class="item"> 8 </div>
  <div class="item"> 9 </div>
  <div class="item"> 10 </div>
  <div class="item"> 11 </div>
  <div class="item"> 12 </div>
  <div class="item"> 13 </div>
  <div class="item"> 14 </div>
  <div class="item"> 15 </div>
  <div class="item"> 16 </div>
  <div class="item"> 17 </div>
  <div class="item"> 18 </div>
  <div class="item"> 19 </div>
  <div class="item"> 20 </div>
  <div class="item"> 21 </div>
  <div class="item"> 22 </div>
  <div class="item"> 23 </div>
  <div class="item"> 24 </div>
  <div class="item"> 25 </div>
  <div class="item"> 26 </div>
  <div class="item"> 27 </div>
  <div class="item"> 28 </div>
  <div class="item"> 29 </div>
  <div class="item"> 30 </div>
</div>
```

This is a template to illustrate the result.

I am not sure why some of the blocks are missing on the bottom diagram.

[image: What I expect with the CSS grid]

Comment: This will give you a good understanding of how the `fr` unit works [https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/](https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/). What you have appears to work as it should. Put a border around `.item` to see what I mean.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not understanding. I understand the info you referenced but even when using fr alone or mixed values, I still don't understand why rows won't recognize fr values but the columns will.

Comment: _The fr unit can be used for grid-rows and grid-columns values. It stands for “fraction of available space”. Think of it as percentages for available space when you’ve taken off fixed-sized and content-based columns/rows. As the spec says:_

_The distribution of fractional space occurs after all ‘length’ or content-based row and column sizes have reached their maximum._ [source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-rows-columns/#article-header-id-1). The rows are recognizing the fr values.

Comment: What browser are you using? If it is out-of-date that may explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: The latest version of Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.149).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your container has no extra height. So there's no free space for the `fr` unit to distribute.

Set a height to the container (e.g., `height: 100vh`).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh; /* new */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item"> 1 </div>
  <div class="item"> 2 </div>
  <div class="item"> 3 </div>
  <div class="item"> 4 </div>
  <div class="item"> 5 </div>
  <div class="item"> 6 </div>
  <div class="item"> 7 </div>
  <div class="item"> 8 </div>
  <div class="item"> 9 </div>
  <div class="item"> 10 </div>
  <div class="item"> 11 </div>
  <div class="item"> 12 </div>
  <div class="item"> 13 </div>
  <div class="item"> 14 </div>
  <div class="item"> 15 </div>
  <div class="item"> 16 </div>
  <div class="item"> 17 </div>
  <div class="item"> 18 </div>
  <div class="item"> 19 </div>
  <div class="item"> 20 </div>
  <div class="item"> 21 </div>
  <div class="item"> 22 </div>
  <div class="item"> 23 </div>
  <div class="item"> 24 </div>
  <div class="item"> 25 </div>
  <div class="item"> 26 </div>
  <div class="item"> 27 </div>
  <div class="item"> 28 </div>
  <div class="item"> 29 </div>
  <div class="item"> 30 </div>
</div>
```

---

> I don't understand why this isn't working as the `fr` units are working with `grid-template-columns`.

Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default. So you don't need to define `width: 100%`.

Not so with height. Most elements are set by default to the height of their content (`height: auto`). So you need to define a height if you want the container to be taller than the content.

That's why the `fr` units were working with `grid-template-columns` but not `grid-template-rows`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, that explains it perfectly. I was unaware that the height was set to the content. I thought that it would be set to the viewport instead which was why i was so confused.